# How to allign row to fixed place

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this `List view.builder`

```
child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: coins.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: iconsList[index],
                  title: Wrap(children: [
                    Row(children: [
                      Text(
                        coins[index],
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        value[index],
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ]),
                  ]),
                  subtitle: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Text(
                      value[index],
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
```

It looks like this when showing on screen of mobile:

[image]

I want to place the amount in euro on right top above the coin change like this:

[image]

How should i place the amount in euro's so it will look the example image i showed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` and `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,` under `Row` and no need use subtitle you just bind the right side elements with `Column` and change text style as you need

```
ListTile(
               leading: Icon(Icons.add),
              title: Wrap(children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        "coins[index]1",
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            "value[index]2",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "value[index]3",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )

                    ]),
              ]),

            )
```

output:

[image]